# Signal decompositon

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis, estimation, fourier-series

I am not a good in writing algorithm but please follow below steps

1.There are 4 1D **sinusoidal periodic** signals.3 of them are given by
\begin{cases}
  x(t)=4\sin(10\pi t) \\
  y(t)=8\cos(20\pi t) \\
  z(t)=16\sin(30\pi t) \\ 
 \end{cases}
2. 4th  signal **m(t)**  is calculated as
\begin{cases}
  m(t)=x(t) +y(t)-z(t)
\end{cases}
3.Now,draw the **waveform** of the signal **m(t)**,keep it only with you and forget all **other** signals data.

4.Forget that **m(t)** is composed of 3 above signals . Now you have  **waveform of only one signal i.e. m(t) (not even the equation of the signal  m(t))**

5.Now ,I want to bring back the same above 3 signals(i.e.. **x(t),y(t),z(t)**) from **waveform** of **m(t)** **only**,

So my question is that what is the efficient way to do it?

**Give solution**.

Also, Is there any possibility that we could get totally different signals than above 3 signals ?

Comment: Are the functions in question always sinusoids? If so, this would be a job for a Fourier series (if the overall period of $m(t)$ is known) or a Fourier transform.

Comment: I think your message is a bit lost in translation; I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I stand by my original statement; especially if the basis functions are always sinusoids, this is a job for a Fourier transform.

Comment: That is the method of my choice. Read up on the Fourier transform and you'll see that it projects a signal onto a basis of sinusoidal functions. That's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: looks like you **did** migrate the question here.

Comment: pandu, can you confirm if your basis is sinusoidal?  in other words, is there a possibility of the component signals, $x(t)$, $y(t)$, and $z(t)$ **not** being purely sinusoidal?  in music processing, we have the problem called "source separation" which is a lot harder than just using the Fourier transform to separate sinusoids.

Comment: First, note that $m(t)$ is a periodic single. Use Fourier series to decompose your original signal into constituent components. The FS will give you the three sinusoids back from $m(t)$. You can call the 3  components as  basis functions. Yes.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson sir all of 4 signals are sinusoidal.

Comment: @Oliever sir I don't understand how to apply Fouries series formula on the waveform of m(t). Can you solve for me?

Comment: @pandu what do you know in signal processing ?

Comment: @Antoine Bassoul sir i have studied Fourier theory of series and transform but I don't understand how to apply it on a **waveform** to find the signals it is composed of. Here,I have already  given values of x(t),y(t) and z(t) for simplification.but instead of this if I had given plot of signal waveform of m(t),it would have been difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: @pandu Have you tried to find the fourrier transform of $m(t)$. And i mean calculating it analyticaly, If you have studied fourier theory you should be able to do that. Maybe try it and ask us to explain the steps you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The inner product between $\sin(m \pi t)$ and $\sin(n \pi t)$ is zero if $m \ne n$. The same holds true for inner product between $\sin(m \pi t)$ and $\cos(n \pi t)$ for any integer $m$ and $n$.

You can get back $x(t)$ with the inner product between $m(t)$ and $\sin(10 \pi t)$. *Remember the scaling.*

Code:

```
N=10000;
t=linspace(-1,1,N);
x=4*sin(10*pi*t);
y=8*sin(20*pi*t);
z=16*sin(30*pi*t);
xc=1;yc=1;zc=-1;
m=xc*x+yc*y+zc*z;
xs=(1/xc)*dot(x,m)/dot(x,x);
ys=(1/yc)*dot(y,m)/dot(y,y);
zs=(1/zc)*dot(z,m)/dot(z,z);
xo=xs*x;
yo=ys*y;
zo=zs*z;
assert(norm(xo-x,'inf')<1e-14)
assert(norm(yo-y,'inf')<1e-14)
assert(norm(zo-z,'inf')<1e-14)
```

The code above uses a numerical discretization. The dot product are almost exact approximation of the integral. Cf. http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/1734/1/NA-13-15.pdf for details.

Comment: if possible ,can you add what steps(algorithm) you have taken for forming your code and your code output results.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is relatively broad in the sense that the difficulty could vary greatly depending on the sampling rate, the avaible signal length and the noise.

I assume a high sampling rate of 1 kHz, 10s of available signal and no noise.

The first solution is to use a fft's magnitude, it works only if all the frequencies are different (if you have a cos and a sine with the same frequency, you'll have to check the phases too) :

```
Fs=1e3; %sampling frequency
T=1/Fs; %sampling period
N=10/T; %Number of points to have 10s of signal
f=Fs*linspace(0,1,N);
Fm=(1/N)*fft(m); %Normalization
Fm=2*Fm(1:length(t)/2); %Get rid of the negatives frequencies

figure, plot(f,Fm)
xlabel('frequency (hz)')
ylabel('Magnitude')
```

[image]

Here's a zoom on the fft's plot. Then you have to extract the peaks which is very easy if the noise is low and if you know how many peaks there is. I stress it again, it is much more difficult if you have high noise / low sampling frequency / short signal available only.

An another solution is to directly estimate your system's parameters.

$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=A \sin(2 \pi f_x t) \\
y(t)=B \sin(2 \pi f_y t)  \\
z(t)=C \sin(2 \pi f_z t) 
\end{cases}
$$

You can estimate the parameter $\Theta=[A,B,C,f_x,f_y,f_z]^t$ by optimizing a least square criterion with Gauss-Newton method, let's write $C(\Theta)$ such a criterion, $m(t_k)$ your discretised measurments and $m_{\theta}(t_k)$ the model with given parameter $\Theta$.

$$
C(\Theta)=\sum_{k=1}^{N} (m(t_k)-m_{\theta}(t_k))^2
$$
The parameter's value $\hat{\Theta}$ we're looking for is given by :
$$
\hat{\Theta}=\arg_{\Theta}\min C(\Theta)
$$
We find the minimum by searching $\hat{\Theta}$ such that $\nabla_{\Theta}C(\hat{\Theta})=0$

There you go with Gauss-Newton, the most difficult part being to calculate the model's gradient $\nabla_{\Theta}m_{\Theta}(t_k)$.

I assume you know how to proceed.

On a practical point of view, you may have to run the optimization routine multiple time with random initializations as it is possible that it gets stuck in local minimas.